# Hourglass sums using java 8 IntStream

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

I am trying to solve the [Maximum sum of hour glass in matrix](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-hour-glass-matrix/):

> Given a 2D matrix, the task is that we find maximum sum of a hour glass.
>
> An hour glass is made of 7 cells
>   in following form.
>
> ```
> A B C
>   D
> E F G
> ```

Something is wrong with my implementation, and I am getting weird answers. I am supposed to get 19 but it returns 36.

Here is my code:

```
static int hourglassSums(int[][] arr)
{
    return IntStream.range(0, 4).map(x -> {
        return IntStream.range(0, 4).map(y ->
                  arr[y][x] + arr[y][x + 1] + arr[y][x + 2] 
                  + arr[y + 1][x + 1] 
                  + arr[y + 2][x] + arr[y + 2][x + 1] + arr[y + 2][x + 2]
        ).sum();
    }).max().getAsInt();
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Max sum :: " + hourglassSums(new int[][] {
                    {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0}
    }));
}
```

Comment: would be better to include the description of the task as well within your post. Further, post the result you're currently getting and what you expect instead.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't use Streams here, it brings no benefits. Stick with the `for-loop` statement rather.

Comment: @JoeC, Sorry for not including the expected results. May be you over look the link I have included in the description. You should have clicked it. Funny you don't see it.

Comment: @Aomine, Sorry I missed the expected results. But included the problem description in the link.

Comment: A good question on this site must be useful to future readers.  If the link changes, your question ceases to become useful to future visitors.  While including a link for reference is perfectly fine, important information should be included in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are iterating 4 times (`0 - 3`) and but the hourglass is only supposed to be `3` numbers at its widest. you need to iterate only 3 times (0 - 2):

```
static int hourglassSums(int[][] arr) {
    return IntStream.range(0, 3).map(x -> {
        return IntStream.range(0, 3).map(y ->
                arr[y][x] + arr[y][x + 1] + arr[y][x + 2] 
                + arr[y + 1][x + 1] 
                + arr[y + 2][x] + arr[y + 2][x + 1] + arr[y + 2][x + 2]
        ).sum();
    }).max().getAsInt();
}
```

***Output:***

```
19
```

Which is from the hourglass:

```
2, 4, 4, 
   2, 
1, 2, 4
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. It returns the correct result, 19, by coincidence. It has the same problem of the OPs code - it calculates the sum of multiple hour glasses instead of just 1. In this case 3 hour-glasses (100/0/100 (sum 2) + 000/0/244 (sum 10) + 100/4/020 (sum 7) equals 19). The only difference compared to the OP's code is that you skip some of the hour glasses, including the hour-glass having the max sum.

Comment: @AnilKumarC It appears my answer is not correct. Please unnaccept my answer and accept Eran's

Comment: @Eran It will not allow me to delete my answer as it is accepted, but I have asked the OP to unnaccept my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You are already computing the sum of each hour glass inside your inner `map` call. Therefore your `sum()` terminal operation applied on the inner `IntStream` makes no sense, since it adds the sums of multiple hour glasses.

Your code actually returns 38, which is the sum of the following hour glasses:

```
hour      hour
glass     glass
          sum

1 0 0
  0          2
1 0 0

0 0 0
  0         10
2 4 4

1 0 0        
  4          7
0 2 0

2 4 4 
  2         19
1 2 4
            --
            38
```

You can fix this by finding the max sum of the inner `IntStream`, and then the max sum of the outer `IntStream`:

```
static int hourglassSums(int[][] arr) {
      return IntStream.range(0, 4).map(x -> {
          return IntStream.range(0, 4).map(y ->
                  arr[y][x] + arr[y][x + 1] + arr[y][x + 2] 
                  + arr[y + 1][x + 1] 
                  + arr[y + 2][x] + arr[y + 2][x + 1] + arr[y + 2][x + 2]
          ).max().getAsInt(); // find the max hour glass sum of all the hour
                              // glasses starting at column x
      }).max().getAsInt(); // find the overall max hour glass sum
}
```

This results in

```
Max sum :: 19
```

A better alternative would be to use `flatMap`:

```
static int hourglassSums(int[][] arr) {
      return IntStream.range(0, 4)
                      .flatMap(x -> IntStream.range(0, 4)
                                             .map(y -> arr[y][x] +
                                                       arr[y][x + 1] +
                                                       arr[y][x + 2] +
                                                       arr[y + 1][x + 1] +
                                                       arr[y + 2][x] +
                                                       arr[y + 2][x + 1] +
                                                       arr[y + 2][x + 2]))
                      .max()
                      .getAsInt();
}
```

This way you create an `IntStream` of all the hour glass sums and find the max value of that stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int getMaxHour(Integer[][] arr) {
    return IntStream.range(0, 4).map(y -> {
        return IntStream.range(0, 4).map(x -> arr[y][x] + arr[y][x + 1] + 
           arr[y][x + 2] + arr[y + 1][x + 1]
            + arr[y + 2][x] + arr[y + 2][x + 1] + 
           arr[y + 2][x +2]).max().getAsInt();
      }).max().getAsInt();
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).